# Upload Image to Cloud Storage from Cloud Function Trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently seeking some help with my Cloud Function that is triggered by a Cloud Storage Upload. It checks if the file is a Video, if so we process this Video through ffmpeg to extract a single frame to be used for a Poster Image later.

It all seems to work except my upload of the image back to Cloud Storage doesn't work. At this point where my Cloud Function is it doesn't produce any errors at all, so i have no clue why the upload of the image to Cloud Storage is not working. I would greatly appreciate if anyone with the experience can review my Cloud Function below and provide some insight into why it's not working. Please advice if possible!! Thank you!!!! ^_^

Note: Screenshot of Cloud Function Log is provided below the code snippet

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); // Firebase Admin SDK
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); // Firebase Cloud Functions
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')(); // Cloud Storage Node.js Client
const path = require('path'); // Node.js file and directory utility
const os = require('os'); // Node.js operating system-related utility
const fs = require('fs'); // Node.js file system API
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;

// Initialize Firebase Admin
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listen for changes in Cloud Storage bucket
exports.storageFunction = functions.storage.object()
  .onChange((event) => {
    const file = event.data; // The Storage object.
    const fileBucket = file.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = file.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath); // Get the file name.
    const fileType = file.contentType; // File content type.

    if (!fileType.startsWith('video/')) {
      return;
    }

    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    const tempFolderPath = os.tmpdir();

    // Download video to temp directory
    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tempFilePath
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Video downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);

      // Generate screenshot from video
      ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
        .setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
        .setFfprobePath(ffprobePath)
        .on('filenames', (filenames) => {
          console.log(`Will generate ${filenames}`);
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
          console.log(`An error occurred: ${err.message}`);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log(`Output image created at ${tempFilePath}`);

          const targetTempFileName = `${fileName}.png`;
          const targetFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), targetTempFileName);

          console.log(targetTempFileName);
          console.log(targetFilePath);

          // Uploading the image.
          return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, { destination: targetFilePath })
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Output image uploaded to', filePath);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
        })
        .screenshots({
          count: 1,
          folder: tempFolderPath
        });
    });
});
```

[Cloud Function Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgIqs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to return a promise from the ffmpeg callback API:

```
.on('end', () => {
   return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, { destination: targetFilePath })
   .then(...)
})
```

I don't know the ffmpeg API, but I'm almost certain that will not cause the function to wait for the upload to complete.  Instead, you need to [return a promise from directly from your function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that resolves only after *all* the async work is complete.

If the last item of work is inside a callback, and you need to wait for that, you can wrap the entire thing into a new promise and manually resolve it at the right time.  In pseudocode:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ffmpeg stuff here...
    .on('end', () => {
        // the last bit of work here...
        bucket.upload(...)
        .then(() => { resolve() })
    })
})
```

Notice how the `resolve` method provided by the new promise is being called to indicate when that promise should itself resolve.

Comment: Thanks so much!! OK, so now with that I finally seem to get some feedback, and received an ApiError: https://imgur.com/G0rZy7c



`textPayload:  "ApiError: Not Found
    at Object.parseHttpRespMessage (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:161:33)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:136:18)
    at Duplexify.self.requestStream.on.on.res (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js:542:21)`

see screenshot (above link) for more details.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem that's unrelated to the first one.  In that case, it's helpful to ask another question (outside of this one) with a description of what's going on.